# How to use rails jbuilder outside of views

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

It is possibile to use jbuilder fragment caching outside of views?

I am trying to use jbuilder with caching in the following way:

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.cache! ['v1', @people], expires_in: 10.minutes do
    json.array! @people do |person|
      json.id    person.id
      json.name  person.name
    end
  end
end
```

Json output conatins actually "cache!" instead of doing caching.

Output example: 
   `"{\"version\":1,\"people\":{\"cache!\":[[{\"id\":1,\"name\"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible but it's not that simple, because `cache!` and `array!` are both defined in [JbuilderTemplate](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/master/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb#L51) that needs a view context. You can use the `JbuilderTemplate` in Rails controllers like this:

```
template = JbuilderTemplate.encode(view_context) do |json|
  json.cache! ['v1', @people], expires_in: 10.minutes do
    json.array! @people do |person|
      json.id    person.id
      json.name  person.name
    end
  end
end
```

It's important to set the `view_context`. Outside of controllers it's better to use `Rails.cache.fetch` (in fact, that's exactly what [Jbuilder does](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/master/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb#L53)).

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I have used `Rails.cache.fetch`.